# How to convert Action to Func<Task> without running the Task?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I have code that works precisely as desired. However, our corporate build server rejects any check-in that has a compiler warning.

The following warning is (as expected) displayed for the Action constructor with the Action to Func conversions, since I am not using an await statement.

> This async method lacks 'await' operators and will run synchronously. Consider using the 'await' operator to await non-blocking API calls, or 'await Task.Run(...)' to do CPU-bound work on a background thread.

```
public class TransactionOperation
{
    private readonly Func<Task> _operation;
    private readonly Func<Task> _rollback;

    public OperationStatus Status { get; private set; }

    public TransactionOperation(Func<Task> operation, Func<Task> rollback)
    {
        _operation = operation;
        _rollback = rollback;
        Status = OperationStatus.NotStarted;
    }

    public TransactionOperation(Action operation, Action rollback)
    {
        _operation = async () => operation.Invoke();
        _rollback = async () => rollback.Invoke();
        Status = OperationStatus.NotStarted;
    }

    public async Task Invoke()
    {
        try
        {
            Status = OperationStatus.InProcess;
            await _operation.Invoke();
            Status = OperationStatus.Completed;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //...
        }
    }
}
```

What is a correct way to rewrite that code so that the Action is correctly converted to Func without being executed yet or creating a new thread (i.e. await Task.Run())?

---

**Update - Proposed Answer #1**

> _operation = () => new Task(operation.Invoke);
>
> _rollback = () => new Task(rollback.Invoke);

I tried this before. It causes this unit test to never return.

```
[TestMethod, TestCategory("Unit Test")]
public async Task Transaction_MultiStepTransactionExceptionOnFourthAction_CorrectActionsRolledBack()
{
    var operation = new TransactionOperation(PerformAction, () => RollbackOperation(1));
    var operation2 = new TransactionOperation(PerformAction, () => RollbackOperation(2));
    var operation3 = new TransactionOperation(PerformAction, () => RollbackOperation(3));
    var operation4 = new TransactionOperation(ExceptionAction, () => RollbackOperation(4));
    var operation5 = new TransactionOperation(PerformAction, () => RollbackOperation(5));
    var transaction = new Transaction(new[] { operation, operation2, operation3, operation4, operation5 });

    await IgnoreExceptions(transaction.ExecuteAsync);

    AssertActionsPerformedThrough(4);
    AssertActionsRolledBackThrough(4);
}
```

---

**Update - Accepted Answer**

```
private async Task ConvertToTask(Action action)
{
    action.Invoke();
    await Task.FromResult(true);
}
```

Here's the updated Action constructor:

```
public TransactionOperation(Action operation, Action rollback)
{
    _operation = () => ConvertToTask(operation);
    _rollback = () => ConvertToTask(rollback);
    Status = OperationStatus.NotStarted;
}
```

Comment: Why are you doing async on a thing that will run synchronously?

Comment: Well, `async () => { operation.Invoke(); await Task.FromResult(0); }` should do it, but the above comment is still relevant: why do you want to wrap synchronous code as asynchronous, in the first place?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can just use `Task.FromResult(0)`:

```
_operation = async () => { operation.Invoke(); await Task.FromResult(0); };
```

Comment: Any reason not to use `await Task.CompletedTask` rather than `Task.FromResult(0)`?

Comment: @ShaulBehr: No. It just didn't exist at the time the answer was written.

Answer (score 2):

You mean like this:

```
_operation = () => new Task(operation.Invoke);
_rollback = () => new Task(rollback.Invoke);
```

The functions will then return a task with the desired action which have not yet been started.

I think you'll need to update your `Invoke` method to the below to get the behaviour you're looking for:

```
Status = OperationStatus.InProcess;
await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        _operation().Start();
        _operation().Wait();
    });
Status = OperationStatus.Completed;
```

Comment: With my current calling syntax, that causes a Unit Test to hang. 
Will edit my question/

Comment: What's the Unit test doing?

Comment: I have looked at your updates. It seems that calling "await _operation.Invoke()" and calling "_operation.Invoke().Start()" would be mutually exclusive. The goal is to be able to use the same execution syntax.

Comment: @SilasReinagel I think you may need to do something like: `await Task.Run(() => _operation().Wait());` in your invoke method to get this functionality. (See edit to answer)

Comment: I tried that and another variation on that, in addition to your latest answer update. It seems like something along those lines should work. However, it stills hangs my unit tests.

Comment: You'll need to post more of the code I think. What happens in `transaction.ExecuteAsync` and `PerformAction` for example? I assume it's hanging on the `await` so my guess is there's a task not getting started somewhere.

Comment: Updated my question with more context. transaction.ExecuteAsync was mistaken named "Invoke()" in my source code sample. I do concur that some Task is not getting started correctly. I'm not sure where or how.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73820/discussion-between-ragtimewilly-and-silas-reinagel).

Comment: @RagtimeWilly, you may as well do `task.RunSynchronously(TaskScheduler.Default)` instead of `Task.Start/Wait`. That'd avoid involving another thread, at least.